# Cassandra filter data from frozen list

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

As of now using Java 8 stream to filter the data from Cassandra frozen type and would like to know whether we can use the spring data Cassandra query to get the inventorynumber field from testingtype.

```
CREATE TABLE sample.testing (id bigint PRIMARY KEY,items list lessthan frozen lessthantestingtype greatherthan greatherthan)

CREATE TYPE sample.testingtype (itemid int,inventorynumber text);
```

Data:

```
Select * from testing

id    | items        

 1    | [{itemid: 10, inventorynumber: '123456'}, {itemid: 20, inventorynumber: '1234567'}
```

Comment: Have you tried `cqlTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT  items FROM sample.testing", List.class)`?

Comment: mp911de - this solution will not help me. I want to get inventorynumber = 123456 from testingtype